# jquery mobile error into javascript google console

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm building a jquery mobile site and I have an error.In my googlejavascript interface error I receive this error

```
Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" not recognized. Content ignored.
```

I haven't any idea how could be since I don't know anything about javascript

what could be?what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "device-width" only works for mobile devices. If you are testing on most normal desktop browsers, they will not know how to handle it. No harm will be done, however - they simply ignore it and note it in the console - nothing that will bother regular users.

(You may also get similar messages if you apply orientation:portrait or orientation:landscape specific styles or meta tags)

Answer (score 3):

Acording to [this page](http://alxgbsn.co.uk/2011/11/23/make-sure-to-use-correct-meta-viewport-syntax/?post=make-sure-to-use-correct-meta-viewport-syntax), the syntax of viewport meta tag is incorrect.

Even though iPad wont complain about it, it should be

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

And not

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;" />
```

Notice the colon instead of semicolons

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't mean much. It basically is more of an error because the browser doesn't know how to handle the code that is meant for another device. So it freaks out and gives an error though it's just the browser not understanding what this means.